# Post link indexed only as images. Doesn't return in SERP when searching for the exact URL

Tags: seo, technical-seo

Lately, when I'm searching for my posts in Google with the exact URL, Google only returns the images from that post, but not the actual title and description in the results.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Can you add screenshot to demonstrate what you're searching for and what's being displayed?

Comment: Of course. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/CV4VTf6.png What's blurry is my link.

Comment: It's best if you edit the screenshot into your question. It appears from that the title and description is being displayed from Pinterest, and is consistent with other results from that site. There's really no way to control what Google returns for search terms, even for exact URLs, unless you use [site:](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433), for example:  `site:https://example.com/your_url`. Google returns the results it feels best match the search terms used based on a number of different factors, including location.

Comment: Most users do not search for URLs, just terms, so if that's really a goal, then try adding branded terms to your URLs that also match their content - see: [Influencing your title links in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/title-link).